# What are the strengths and limitations of the antenna design of the Montjuïc Communications Tower?

Tags: electrical-engineering, telecommunication, electromagnetism, rf-electronics

The [Montjuïc antenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montju%C3%AFc_Communications_Tower) is an interesting design for an antenna.  I presume the design is principally an antenna, but perhaps it is not?  If the ring + mast is an antenna, how does the ring work to augment the mast of the antenna?  Is there something that lets us know that the mast contains many smaller antenna, and the ring is just for aesthetics?

(I've heard it is also [a sundial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montju%C3%AFc_Communications_Tower#Sundial), so maybe the ring is purely to act as an horologue?)

[image]

Comment: Do you mean “sundial” ?

Comment: Unless Barcelona has recently moved to the north pole, a *vertical* structure is useless to make an *accurate* sundial. You need a "pointer" that points to the position of the pole star in the sky, not a vertical one.

Comment: can you furnish a photo?

Comment: @alephzero now that there's a photo, the lower structure may well be pointing to Polaris